# Inserting Upward Triangle In Mathtext String Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, plot, text

I am using the function plt.text in Matplotlib to produce text within my plot. In addition, I am using Mathtext to bold a portion of the text string, as seen in this piece of code:

```
plt.text(0.01,0.32,fill(r"$\bf{Peaks:}$"+appended_text,57), ha='left',va="top", multialignment="left", fontsize=10.5, wrap=True)
```

Within my plot, I am currently denoting specific points with an filled upward triangle (`"^"` via `plt.plot` in Matplotlib), and would like to use this filled upward triangle symbol within the Mathtext bolded string above.

My initial approach was to try: `r"$\bf{Peaks\ [^]:}$"`, however this simply moved the closed portion of the bracket as an exponential symbol.

Is there a way to replicate this filled triangle within Mathtext?

How would I use

Comment: How about `\blacktriangle`?

Comment: That solves the issue, thank you! Is there a document or article with the Mathtext equivalents for other symbols that I can refer to?

Comment: I don't know of such a document, or whether one would make sense.  What I mean is, I'm not sure whether 'mathtext' is a subset of TeX in matplotlib (in which case a mapping would make sense) or whether mathtext and TeX are parallel systems with similar goals, in which case, they would probably use different fonts, etc. More specifically, I don't know how mathtex represents the black triangle, as TeX, Unicode, or ?. I'm sure someone here knows but I don't. (Also, if you want to be sure of identical characters from the same font, you could plot with TeX symbols in the first place.)